# If the inner automorphism group of a group $G$ is residually finite, then $G$ is residually finite group.

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of the center of the group $G$ (so $H$ is normal in $G$). Suppose that $G/H$ is a residually finite group, then is it true that $G$ is a residually finite group?

Moreover, what can we say about the residual finiteness of the inner automorphism group of $G$ when $H$ is a proper subgroup of the center?

Comment: Subgroups of the center are *always* normal. What do you mean, "Suppose that $H$ is normal in $G$" ?

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong; I got confused.

Comment: The second question is senseless... it makes an assumption on $H$, and then asks about something unrelated to $H$.

Comment: @YCor: I think the second question is supposed to be: "Suppose $H$ is a proper subgroup of the center of $G$, and $G/H$ is residually finite; can we say something about the residual finiteness of the inner automorphism of $G$?" (i.e., going from information about $G/H$ to $G/Z(G)$, which is a quotient of the former)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks; so it's a kind of converse... At least if $H=1$, $G=G/H$ residually finite implies $G/Z$ residually finite (because the center $Z$ is then closed in the profinite topology).

Comment: The question whether $G/H$ residually finite for some subgroup $H$ of the center $Z$ of $G$, implies that $G$ is residually finite, is a separate question of independent interest, and seems not easy. I suggest to post it on MathOverflow.

Comment: @YCor, do you know of a reference for the claim that G/Center(G) is residually finite if G is?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't have a reference. But here's a proof (already sketched above): if $G$ is residually finitee, then its profinite topology is Hausdorff, and hence its center is closed. Hence its center is an intersection of finite index subgroup, which means that the quotient by the center is residually finite.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not true: while f.g. metabelian groups are all residually finite, there are center-by-metabelian f.g. groups that are not residually finite. Here's an example due to Ph. Hall (multi-recyclable to many group-theoretic questions).

Write
$$M(t,x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & z\\ 0 & t & y\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad d(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad \zeta(z)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & z\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Fix a prime $p$. Let $G_0$ be the group of matrices $M(p^n,x,y,z)$ when $n$ ranges over $\mathbf{Z}$ and $(x,y,z)$ over $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^3$. It's finitely generated, and its center $Z$ consists of those $\zeta(z)$ for $z\in\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$. Let $Z'$ be the central subgroup of those $\zeta(z)$ for $z\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $G=G_0/Z'$. Its center is reduced to $Z/Z'$.

Conjugation by the matrix $d(p)$ induces a non-injective surjective endomorphism of $G$, which is therefore not Hopfian, hence not residually finite (which is also seen by observing that the Prüfer group $Z/Z'$ is not residually finite).

But the central quotient $G/(Z/Z')=G_0/Z$ is metabelian (it's a semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2$, action by multiplication by $(p,p^{-1})$), hence is residually finite.

---

Other examples:

some come from lattices in Lie groups. E.g., the inverse image of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z}[1/2])$ (residually finite) in the universal (2-fold) covering of $\mathbf{SL}_3(\mathbf{R})$ is, I believe, not residually finite. I'm not sure of a reference, but Deligne and Raghunathan produced others using other arithmetic lattices, and Erschler did a similar game using Grigorchuk's first group.